# Ionic3/iOS: remove "pointer-events: none" does not re-enable scrolling

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3, pointer-events

I have a simple ionic page contains a button that show a model. When the modal is opened the body scroll gets disabled using "pointer-events: none" in app root level.

The issue is when I dismiss(cancel) the modal, "pointer-events: none" is removed but the body stops scrolling, clicking on the button and tapping in input areas are enabled but not the scroll.

This strange behavior is only on iOS, on Android it works great.

Ionic version : 3.20
iOS : 12.4

Comment: Share your Code Please.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/22306#issuecomment-771705291